# angularjs radio group unique name generate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Everything is not working fine. ng-repeat is working fine. It is creating options from json but the problem is every radio has the same name. Because of that only one radio is selectable at a time. how to generate unique name extension for each radio group.

Here is the plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/Vze4y6QEerhiTPX7sEZz?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('q', []);

app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
    this.sets = set;
});// Fin aCtrl

var set = 
[
    { 
        "qus" :"what is your name?",
        "option1" : {"ans" : "Alex", "cor":"false"},
        "option2" : {"ans" : "Hervy", "cor":"false"},
        "option3" : {"ans" : "Rico", "cor":"true"},
        "option4" : {"ans" : "Tom", "cor":"false"},
    },
    { 
        "qus" :"what is your brother's name?",
        "option1" : {"ans" : "Alex", "cor":"false"},
        "option2" : {"ans" : "Hervy", "cor":"true"},
        "option3" : {"ans" : "Rico", "cor":"false"},
        "option4" : {"ans" : "Tom", "cor":"false"},
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate name that contains iteration index. For example like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="op + {{$index}}" ng-value="{{qs.option2.cor}}" ng-model="nv1">
    <span class="up">{{qs.option1.ans}}</span>
</li>
```

So the group names will be `op0`, `op1`, etc.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/sRUa1qhmMlHD8GXGF6PO?p=preview

Comment: Would you mind to explain another thing? What is that $index? Is it built in? What does it do? Thank you.